# How to properly null check/lazy load

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a resource file that I load, when needed, to check if a certain word is among the ones in the file.

I want to get rid of the method-wide synchronized keyword. There's no point in all threads waiting while `wordsInFile.contains(word.toLowerCase());` runs.

Original:

```
private Set<String> wordsInFile = new HashSet<String>;
private static synchronized boolean IsFound(String word)
{
  if (word == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (wordsInFile.isEmpty())
  {
    wordsInFile = new HashSet<String>();

    InputStream inputStream = WebUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("words.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader))
    {
      String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
      while (line != null)
      {
        wordsInFile.add(line);
        line = bufferedReader.readLine(); // they're all lowercase
      }
    }
    catch (Exception aEx)
    {
      ;
    }
  }

  return wordsInFile.contains(word.toLowerCase());
}
```

Is this OK?

```
private Set<String> wordsInFile;
private static boolean IsFound(String word)
{
  if (word == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  synchronized (wordsInFile)
  {
    if (wordsInFile.isEmpty())
    {
      wordsInFile = new HashSet<String>();
    
      InputStream inputStream = WebUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("words.txt");
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    
      try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader))
      {
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
          wordsInFile.add(line);
          line = bufferedReader.readLine(); // they're all lowercase
        }
      }
      catch (Exception aEx)
      {
        ;
      }
    }
  }

  return wordsInFile.contains(word.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: You can't synchronize on `wordsInFile` if it is null. I would synchronize on `this` inside the `if (wordsInFile == null)` block. Also, if the code in your question is your actual code, then you shouldn't have an empty `catch` block.

Comment: @Abra - thanks. It's simplified production code that's used in a million places, I would have to handle the exception in all those places if I were to properly throw that exception. But again it's a static file and if parsing *does* fail, something is seriously wrong anyway and handling it wouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm curious, why not *only* reduce the size of the block, and use `synchronized(this)`? Why also switch the object being synchronized on? If you have code that currently relies on being able to synchronize on this specific object, you break that API.

Comment: _if parsing does fail, something is seriously wrong_ Then shouldn't the program terminate? Ignoring the exception means that your program will continue to run as if the parsing did not fail.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel what do you mean? reduce the size of the synchronized block?

Comment: A `synchronized` in the method declaration is equivalent to a `synchronized(this)` block around all the code of the method. Your example code reduces that block to a part of the code and also switches the object being synchronized on. Why not only reduce the size of the block, why also switch the monitor object?

Comment: It isn't around the whole method, just around the if (null). What does "switch the monitor object" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of @Stewart answer. You can handle lazy load without `synchronize` by making use of class loader for `DictionaryHolder`. This works because JVM won't execute the static initialiser of a class multiple times if two threads called methods of that class at same time:

```
public class WordFinder {
    private static class DictionaryHolder {
        private static final Set<String> words;
        static {
            System.out.println( "Loading words..." );
            words = Set.of("hello","world");
            //words = yourLoadCode();
            System.out.println( "Words loaded..." );
        }

        public static Set<String> dictionary() {
            return words;
        }
    }

    private static void justDoSomething() {
        System.out.println( "Doing something..." );
    }

    private static boolean IsFound(String word) {
        System.out.println( "Checking word " + word + "..." );
        return DictionaryHolder.dictionary().contains( word );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordFinder.justDoSomething();
        WordFinder.IsFound( "foo" );
        WordFinder.IsFound( "hello" );
    }
}
```

Note that the lazy loading class `DictionaryHolder` does not have to be an inner class, it can be declared in any package outside. The above prints lines below confirming the lazy load on first call to `IsFound("foo")`:

```
Doing something...
Checking word foo...
Loading words...
Words loaded...
Checking word hello...
```

It's never a good idea to suppress exceptions. If you think `throws IOException` is inappropriate, catch and re-throw as `new RuntimeException(previousException)` so that callers are alerted to issues.

Comment: Doesn't this mean the set will get loaded even if there's no call to the `IsFound` method? 

This is an utils class with various methods. Calling any method from it will load the `words` set. Correct?

Comment: No, the inner class is static it's load time is not when WordFinder class is loaded, and the set load only occurs on first use of `DictionaryHolder.dictionary()` inside `IsFound`. See the output above and notice that "Checking word foo..." is printed before "Loading words..." and the load is not run again after "Checking word hello...".

Comment: you're indeed right. I could have sworn it would be initialized when first dealing with that class. What is the difference between this static bloc in an inner class and a static class variable?

Comment: `DictionaryHolder` is only being initialised when first dealing with that class, and the first use of `DictionaryHolder` in the code is inside `IsFound` for the call `DictionaryHolder.dictionary()`. Its the static field inside any external class which ensures lazy load works. You could use singleton in DictionaryHolder eg  `private static final DictionaryHolder instance = new DictionaryHolder();` and move load words into a constructor. The `static` block is not important.

Comment: Awesome. I tried different threads and the second thread will wait for the static bloc to run. So all works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this with an inner "holder" class, where the Set is immutable once loaded. Do the loading in the constructor of that class, and create the class lazily, synchronizing on the holder.

Immutable objects don't need to be synchronized across threads.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class WordFinder {

    private static class DictionaryHolder {
        private final Set<String> words;
        private DictionaryHolder() {
            System.out.println( "Loading words..." );
            Set<String> loaded = new HashSet<>();
            try( InputStream in = WordFinder.class.getResourceAsStream( "words.txt" ) ) {
                loaded.addAll( IOUtils.readLines( in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) );
            } catch( IOException ioe ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( ioe );
            }
            this.words = Collections.unmodifiableSet(loaded);
            System.out.println( "Words loaded..." );
        }
    }

    private static DictionaryHolder dictionary = null;

    private static void justDoSomething() {
        System.out.println( "Doing something..." );
    }

    private static boolean IsFound(String word) {
        synchronized( DictionaryHolder.class ) {
            if(dictionary == null) {
                dictionary = new DictionaryHolder();
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Checking word " + word + "..." );
        return dictionary.words.contains( word );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordFinder.justDoSomething();
        WordFinder.IsFound( "foo" );
        WordFinder.IsFound( "bar" );
    }
}
```